# Disable vertical centering of a part title page in titlesec

Tags: titlesec, section-titles

I'm using `titlesec` to re-style my part title page. I would like the part title to appear a fixed distance from the top, but the default behavior for the `page` class is to center it vertically. I want to keep it on its own page (the `page` title class). How do I disable the vertical centering?

I am using `\titlespacing` but it does not appear to have any effect on vertical positioning for a part title on its own page.

I see the default `\part` command has a `\vfil` in it, but I tried redefining `\part` to omit it and that didn't change anything. I'm guessing `titlesec` does its own redefinition of `\part`.

This is everything I want except the fixed vertical spacing isn't working:

```latex
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\assignpagestyle{\part}{empty}

\newcommand\parttitle[1]{\textcolor{White}{\arabic{part} \\ #1}}
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont}{}{0pt}%
    {\newpagecolor{NavyBlue}\afterpage{\restorepagecolor}\filleft\parttitle}%
    {}
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `\titlespacing` command?

Comment: `\titlespacing` doesn't appear to cancel the vertical centering. Let me know if I'm using it incorrectly.

```\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{10pt}{0pt}```

Comment: (Added titlespacing to question; double-checked the result.)